# Jquery function not working on partial view load

Tags: jquery

Hi guys I wrote some jquery that allows me to show and hide textboxes when a checkbox is checked. This code works fine on a regular view but on a partial view it does not load. The code is as follows.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function ()
    {
        $("#monday").hide();

        $("#Monday").click(function () {
            if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                $("#monday").show();
            } else {
                $("#monday").hide();
                $("#MondayStartTime").val("");
                $("#MondayEndTime").val("");
            }
        })})
</script>
```

Monday is the "checkbox" and "monday" is a div that contains textboxes. What is the best/easiest way to load this on partial view load?

Comment: You mean it doesn't work on ajax (or otherwise dynamically) created markup?  http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Comment: I have not included ajax anywhere in my view?

Comment: What do you mean by partial view load then?  Side note: $(this).is(':checked') is the same as just doing this.checked, with more overhead.

Comment: @Taplar what I mean is when I load the main page the partial view is displayed on it straight away but it does not pick up on the jquery. I would like the div "monday" to be hidden straight away.

Comment: Then you need to show some markup cause `$("#monday").hide();` will execute as soon as the entire page body has been loaded into the DOM, since you are in a document ready.  I still don't understand why you are calling it a partial page load.  If your server is returning a page to the user, regardless of if it is putting it together from partials or whatever, all the user sees is a page, and it is that page that the javascript runs against.  Not "partials"